# FTP Not working through TCP Tunnel

Tags: ftp, reverse-proxy

so I am using the following software: tcptunnel. Which is a simple software to  basically forward packets to another server. In this case I use a DDoS protected server to forward data to my unprotected server, so it doesn't get ddosed.

Anyway here is my tcptunnel command, pretty standard

```
/root/tcptunnel/tcptunnel \
--local-port=21 \
--remote-port=21 \
--remote-host=x.x.x.x \
--bind-address=209.141.39.157 \
--fork \
--stay-alive
```

Now if I connect to my FTP server normally with x.x.x.x it works, although when connecting with the protected IP the connection starts and seems to authenticate but doesn't show files.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Status: Connecting to 209.141.39.157:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Multicraft 1.8.2 FTP server
Command:    USER xxxx
Response:   331 Username ok, send password.
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   230 Login successful
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OK
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to: Binary.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering passive mode (x,x,x,x,96)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 File status okay. About to open data connection.
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Answer (score 0):

Note FTP protocol is not NAT transparent. In your case similar situation exists. For the retrieve command, the ip address is the original user's ip address. If you simply forward this command to your server, the server will try send data directly to the original user, which will fail.

To make this work, tcptunnel need understand up layer protocol, and do necessary packet modification before forwarding that data.